# Node.js doesn't display entire error message on uncaughtException, is it possible?

Tags: node.js

In node.js if you catch uncaughtExceptions, like so:

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

The error message displayed doesn't contain all the information that you receive if you don't catch the error and just let the process crash. When you let the process crash it includes what line caused the error. Is there any way to get the full error message including the line that caused the error so we can log this data using uncaughtException.

Comment: This question itself has solved my problem :) Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Try `error.stack`

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function (error) {
   console.log(error.stack);
});
```

Comment: How to show more, because in my case, error.stack just show 3 row, I can not trace the root of issue raising the error

Comment: upvoted! isnt error.stack a nonstandard extension https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error or does node have it everywhere

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function (error) {
   console.dir(error);
});
```

Comment: Sir, Any difference between the question and the answer?

Comment: @Jayram Yes. The question used `console.log(error)` and I suggestion using `console.dir(error)`. Different functions on the `console` object.