# Only disconnect one socket when error occurs in NodeJS program

Tags: sockets, node.js, error-handling

Currently when an error occurs in a NodeJS server (eg: Buffer "out of bounds"), the entire server grinds to a halt. Is there a way to configure it such that only the socket on which the error occured gets disconnected leaving the server online and the other connections active? I could use the "uncaughtException" error but then there would be no way of knowing which socket caused the error/crashed. How is this handled typically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `try .. catch(err)` construct to catch any exceptions occurring within any callback of the the socket, and subsequently `socket.end()`, to disconnect the client if an error occurs. This prevents the entire server from crashing. Obviously for the other "uncaught" errors you'll have to resort to the "uncaughtException" callback, which [does not end the server](http://debuggable.com/posts/node-js-dealing-with-uncaught-exceptions:4c933d54-1428-443c-928d-4e1ecbdd56cb). Why don't you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9558360/node-js-reliability-for-large-application) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310521/node-js-best-practice-exception-handling) for more answers.