# Get a stack trace from a throwed string in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, stack, stack-trace

When I run this code:

```
throw 'a string';
```

I get this stacktrace on my terminal:

```
$ node test.js

/home/user/test.js:2
throw 'a string';
^
a string
```

There is the filename and the line where this exception appeared.

I'm trying to build an exception logging mecanism and when I use the uncaughtException handler, I cannot get the filename nor the line.

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function() {
  console.log(arguments);
});

throw 'a string';
```

When I run this code I only get:

```
$ node test2.js

{ '0': 'a string' }
```

Is is possible to get the filename / line when I use the uncaughtException handler?

Thanks

Comment: If you throw `Error` objects you can get a stack trace from them.

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9181027/node-js-doesnt-display-entire-error-message-on-uncaughtexception-is-it-possibl

Comment: see [Throwing strings instead of Errors](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11502052/1048572)

Answer (score 3):

use `throw new Error('my message');`

> C:\Users\xxx\Desktop>node test.js
>
> C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\test.js:1 (function (exports, require,
>   module, __filename, __dirname) { throw  'test';
>                                                                 ^ test

contents of test.js:
`throw 'test';`

> C:\Users\xxx\Desktop>node test2.js
>
> C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\test2.js:1 (function (exports, require,
>   module, __filename, __dirname) { throw new Error(
>                                          ^ Error: test
>       at Object. (C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\test2.js:1:69)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
>       at startup (node.js:119:16)
>       at node.js:906:3

contents of test2.js:
`throw new Error('test');`

also:

> In JavaScript, you can technically `throw` things that are not Errors,
>   but this should be avoided. The result does not include the potential
>   for getting a call stack, nor a "name" property for programmatic
>   inspection, nor any useful properties describing what went wrong.

from [Error Handling in Node.js](https://www.joyent.com/developers/node/design/errors)

Comment: I know but I'm trying to log error of submodules I am using, that may throw string only...

Answer (score 0):

You can't get a stack trace from a throwed `string`. In fact it's the `Error` object that builds the stack.

You might think of a workaround that would build a `new Error` when an exception is caught, but the stack trace won't go back to the throwed string.

Solution: never throw strings, use errors instead.